# @Transactional method called from @Async method in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

```
class A {
     @Autowired
     B b;
     @Async
     public void updateDBAsync(){
         b.updateDBTransactional(); 
     }
}

class B {
     @Transactional
     public void updateDBTransactional() {
         // Updating DB from here
     }
}
```

Now Issue is - trying to call a.updateDBAsync() from two different machine at same time. In DB data is getting corrupted. Do anyone has any idea why this is happening and any solution?